# Which scripture gives oldest refrence to samudra mathanam (churning of ocean)

Tags: scripture, vedas, history

we know that samudra mathanam story is popular in epics (Mahabharata, Ramayana) but when its first roots were seen from vedic age and how the story evolved scriptures to scriptures.

Comment: Related and may be a possible duplicate of https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21546/5212

Comment: @ Nog Shine i know abot amrita in vedas. Soma causes immortality in vedas but i want to know wether in brahmanas,aranyakas,upnishads etc. have roots of this story and how the story evolved since scriptures.

Comment: During Samudra manthan, three popular incarnations of Lord Vishnu happened i.e. Kurma, Dhanvantari and Mohini. Also, all the wealth and prosperity emerged again which was lost earlier due to some incidents. Goddess Lakshmi emerged again during Samundra manthan and reunited with Lord Vishnu. This story might not be in Vedas because Vedas were spoken by Lord Bhrahma to sages in the very beginning but this story is present in most of the scriptures which tell the incidents of 7th manvantar i.e. after this story (6th Manavantar).

Comment: well i thought it might have its earlier roots in brahmanas,aranyakas,upnishads
etc. but no problem its okay.
I was in a mood to know how new incidents were added to the story. well its already present here — https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samudra_manthan 
so, no problem and thanks@yds.